# How can I upload data via HTTParty in Ruby while generating it?

Tags: ruby, http, httparty

I have a function which generates some data. Right now, this data is written to a file. Once the file is complete, I upload it via HTTParty:

```rb
require 'httparty'

url = "..."

def generate_data(file)
  file << "First line of data\n"
  sleep 1
  file << "Second line of data\n"
  sleep 1
  file << "Third line of data\n"
end

File.open('payload.txt', 'w+') do |file|
  generate_data(file)
  file.rewind
  HTTParty.post(url, body: {file: file})
end
```

As it happens, `generate_data` takes a bit -- I would like to accelerate the script *and* avoid writing to disk by interleaving the generation of the data and uploading it. How could I do this using HTTParty?

I was looking for something like `StringIO` which could be used as a fixed-size FIFO buffer: the `generate_data` function writes to it (and blocks when the buffer is full) while the `HTTParty.post` call reads from it. (and blocks when the buffer is empty). However, I failed to find anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [streaming](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/8ceb806b09d0e14ee5be00804a4fc2ce69eae079/examples/body_stream.rb)

```
HTTParty.put(
  'http://localhost:3000/train',
  body_stream: StringIO.new('foo')
)
```